# Modify the vim configuration

Tags: vimrc

In the vim editor, the buffers look like `l/t/l/c/admin.py` for `loanwolf/test/loanwolf/customers/admin.py`. My point is I want to see something like `admin.py (cus)`. How could I modify the `.vimrc` config to obtain something similar?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Offhand that looks more like a modify the source code issue than a  .vimrc setting.

Comment: Where do you see that? in status line, in tab line? A screenshot maybe? or/and link to your `.vimrc`

Answer (score 2):

## Airline

This question relates more to the [vim-airline](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline) plugin than to vim itself. I only mention that because it is easier to answer a question that is well-defined :P.

The vim-airline docs describe [how to format buffer names](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline/blob/master/doc/airline.txt#L642).

## Step by Step

Basically create a file named

`<vim-airline directory>/autoload/airline/extensions/tabline/formatters/foo.vim`.

that contains the following:

```
function! airline#extensions#tabline#formatters#foo#format(bufnr, buffers)
    return bufname(a:bufnr)
endfunction
```

The function above would return the full file path I believe, but you can modify it to return any string you want. Once that is done, add this next line to your `.vimrc`:

```
let g:airline#extensions#tabline#formatter = 'foo'
```

And you should be good to go from there.